# Leetcode question 489. Robot Room Cleaner - why my solution doesn't work

Tags: c++, recursion, backtracking

I am trying to solve the Leetcode question [489. Robot Room Cleaner](https://leetcode.com/problems/robot-room-cleaner/) using backtracking. Specifically, I try to move the robot in each of 4 directions and backtrack if all four directions are blocked or cleaned.

The code below doesn't work and I am trying to debug it with this simple example:

```
grid = [[1,1,1],
        [1,0,1]]
```

where 1 means cell is accessible by a robot and 0 means cell is blocked. The robot starts at this initial position:

```
initial_row = 0
initial_col = 1
```

After I run my code, the the robot only cleaned the right part of the grid (c - cleaned, d - left dirty):

```
[[d,c,c],
 [d,0,c]]
```

It seems to backtrack correctly to the cell [0,1], and it tries to move to the upper-left corner (cell [0,0]), but the robot.move() returns false and the function returns before cleaning the upper-left corner.
I would appreciate any suggestions of what might be going wrong.

Code:

```
struct hsh {
  size_t operator() (const pair<int,int>& p) const {
      hash<int> intHash;
      return intHash(p.first) ^ intHash(p.second);
  }  
};

class Solution {
public:
    unordered_set<pair<int, int>, hsh> cleaned;
    vector<int> directions {0, 1, 2, 3}; // up, down, right, left
    
    void cleanRoom(Robot& robot) {
       
        int row_s = 0; // relative start row
        int col_s = 0; // relative start col
            
        clean(row_s, col_s, robot);
    }

    void clean(int row, int col, Robot& robot) {
    
        cleaned.insert({row, col});
        robot.clean();
    
        for (int dir : directions) {
        
            if (!is_cleaned(row, col, dir)) {
                turn(robot, dir);
            
                if (robot.move()) {
                    turn_back(robot, dir);
                
                    int row_new = get_new_row(row, dir);
                    int col_new = get_new_col(col, dir);
                
                    clean(row_new, col_new, robot);
                } else {
                    turn_back(robot, dir);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    bool is_cleaned(int row, int col, int dir) {
        int row_new = get_new_row(row, dir);
        int col_new = get_new_col(col, dir);
            
        if(cleaned.find({row_new, col_new}) != cleaned.end()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    
    }

    void turn(Robot& robot, int dir) {
        if (dir == 0) { // up
        } else if (dir == 1) { // down
            robot.turnLeft();
            robot.turnLeft();
        } else if (dir == 2) { // right
            robot.turnRight();
        } else { // left
            robot.turnLeft();
        }
    }

    void turn_back(Robot& robot, int dir) {
        if (dir == 0) { // back to up from up
        } else if (dir == 1) { // back to up from down
            robot.turnLeft();
            robot.turnLeft();
        } else if (dir == 2) { // back to up from right
            robot.turnLeft();
        } else { // back to up from left
            robot.turnRight();
        }
    }

    int get_new_row(int row, int dir) {
        if (dir == 0) { // up
            row--; 
            return row;
        } else if (dir == 1) { // down
            row++; 
            return row;
        }
    
        return row;
    }

    int get_new_col(int col, int dir) {
        if (dir == 2) { // right
            col++; 
            return col;
        } else if (dir == 3) { // left
            col--; 
            return col;
        }
    
        return col;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the Robot class interface doesn't put the robot back automatically when backtracking (Robot object is passed by reference and keeps its position). Adding a specific function to move the robot back after backtracking fixed the problem:

```
void go_back(Robot& robot, int dir) {
    // Keep mind that the robot always ends up facing up after every move
    if (dir == 0) { // moved up - returning down
        robot.turnLeft();
        robot.turnLeft();
        robot.move();
        robot.turnLeft();
        robot.turnLeft();
    } else if (dir == 1) { // moved down - returning up
        robot.move();
    } else if (dir == 2) { // moved right - returning left
        robot.turnLeft();
        robot.move();
        robot.turnRight();
    } else { // moved left - returning right
        robot.turnRight();
        robot.move();
        robot.turnLeft();
    }
}
```

Then call this function within the recursive clean() function:

```
void clean(int row, int col, Robot& robot) {
    
    cleaned.insert({row, col});
    robot.clean();
            
    for (int dir : directions) {
                    
        if (!is_cleaned(row, col, dir)) {
            turn(robot, dir);
            
            if (robot.move()) {
                turn_back(robot, dir);
                
                int row_new = get_new_row(row, dir);
                int col_new = get_new_col(col, dir);
                
                clean(row_new, col_new, robot);
                
                go_back(robot, dir); // Move the robot back while backtracking!
                
            } else {
                turn_back(robot, dir);
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please take a look at the detailed-explanation and code below:-

```
'''
The robot will start from (0,0) moving right (from top left)
When the Robot hits (X or 1) robot will turn the clock and move
example:
- moving right then hits (X) or reaches the end of Rooms.
- the robot will move down and keep moving until it hits (X) or reach the bottom
- the robot will move left  and keep moving until it hits (X) or reach the first room (index=0)
- the robot will move up and keep moving until it hits (X) or reach the Top first room (index=0)
- room will be count once so if the robot cross one room more thank one time its still count as one.
'''
def RobotMove(x, y, direction, array, cleaned, looping):
    # Need check as function need exit condition to work correctly
    # I put 20X20 it was the rule that max rooms are 20
    if looping > 400:
        # print("Exit With Rooms cleanes", len(cleaned))
        return len(cleaned)
    else:
        looping_new = looping+1
    max_Y_axis = len(array)
    max_X_axis = len(array[0])

    if direction == "right":
        if x+1 < max_X_axis:
            if array[y][x+1] != 1:
                # print("Go right")
                # print("Room number cleared is ", str(x) + "|" + str(y))
                if str(x) + "|" + str(y) not in cleaned:
                    cleaned.append(str(x) + "|" + str(y))
                return RobotMove(x+1, y, "right", array, cleaned, looping_new)
            else:
                # print("Room number cleared is ", str(x) + "|" + str(y))
                # print("Go Down", x, y)
                if str(x) + "|" + str(y) not in cleaned:
                    cleaned.append(str(x) + "|" + str(y))
                return RobotMove(x, y, "down", array, cleaned, looping_new)
        else:
            # print("Room number cleared is ", str(x) + "|" + str(y))
            # print("Go Down", x, y)
            if str(x) + "|" + str(y) not in cleaned:
                cleaned.append(str(x) + "|" + str(y))
            return RobotMove(x, y, "down", array, cleaned, looping_new)

    if direction == "down":
        if y+1 < max_Y_axis:
            if array[y+1][x] != 1:
                # print("Go down")
                # print("Room number cleared is ", str(x) + "|" + str(y))
                if str(x) + "|" + str(y) not in cleaned:
                    cleaned.append(str(x) + "|" + str(y))
                return RobotMove(x, y+1, "down", array, cleaned, looping_new)
            else:
                # print("Room number cleared is ", str(x) + "|" + str(y))
                # print("Go Down", x, y)
                if str(x) + "|" + str(y) not in cleaned:
                    cleaned.append(str(x) + "|" + str(y))
                return RobotMove(x, y, "left", array, cleaned, looping_new)
        else:
            # print("Room number cleared is ", str(x) + "|" + str(y))
            # print("Go Down", x, y)
            if str(x) + "|" + str(y) not in cleaned:
                cleaned.append(str(x) + "|" + str(y))
            return RobotMove(x, y, "left", array, cleaned, looping_new)

    if direction == "left":
        # print("Current point", str(x) + "|" + str(y))
        # print("Next point", str(int(x)-1) + "|" + str(y))
        if x-1 > -1:
            # print("Value is ", array[y][x-1])
            if array[y][x-1] != 1:
                # print("Go left")
                # print("Room number cleared is ", str(x) + "|" + str(y))
                if str(x) + "|" + str(y) not in cleaned:
                    cleaned.append(str(x) + "|" + str(y))
                return RobotMove(x-1, y, "left", array, cleaned, looping_new)
            else:
                # print("Room number cleared is ", str(x) + "|" + str(y))
                # print("Go left", x, y)
                if str(x) + "|" + str(y) not in cleaned:
                    cleaned.append(str(x) + "|" + str(y))
                return RobotMove(x, y, "up", array, cleaned, looping_new)
        else:
            # print("Room number cleared is ", str(x) + "|" + str(y))
            # print("Go left", x, y)
            if str(x) + "|" + str(y) not in cleaned:
                cleaned.append(str(x) + "|" + str(y))
            return RobotMove(x, y, "up", array, cleaned, looping_new)

    if direction == "up":
        if y-1 > -1:
            if array[y-1][x] != 1:
                # print("Go up")
                # print("Room number cleared is ", str(x) + "|" + str(y))
                if str(x) + "|" + str(y) not in cleaned:
                    cleaned.append(str(x) + "|" + str(y))
                return RobotMove(x, y-1, "up", array, cleaned, looping_new)
            else:
                if str(x) + "|" + str(y) not in cleaned:
                    cleaned.append(str(x) + "|" + str(y))
                return RobotMove(x, y, "right", array, cleaned, looping_new)
        else:
            if str(x) + "|" + str(y) not in cleaned:
                cleaned.append(str(x) + "|" + str(y))
            return RobotMove(x, y, "right", array, cleaned, looping_new)

# Output: Total number of Cleaned Rooms 13
Room = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
]


print("Total number of Cleaned Rooms", RobotMove(0, 0, "right", Room, [], 0))
```

Comment: Does not explain what went wrong with the asker's attempt and the code in the wrong language.